# Is there a way to detect if a new dependency has been added to a maven project since it's previous build/release?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

When a transitive dependency changes, there is no direct change in the project I am working on. When I update a dependency that itself brings in new dependencies since its previous version, transitive dependencies are difficult to track and it would be good to know if there is any new library added to the project I am building or the version of an existing transitive dependency has changed.

Is there a maven plugin that can detect a dependency change like this or a maven flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mvn dependency:list -Dsort=true > file` to generate all dependencies into file. After POM changes generate second file. Then diff files to see changes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do any changes also transitive dependencies will not change. This can happen only if you change POM. For example you change version of used dependency.

If a library changes dependencies, version of the library will increase. To be affected by this changes you would need to use that new version in POM.

Comment: Correct, but how will I know I am being affected by it? Lets say I update the version of a certain direct dependency. How will I know the changes in my transitive dependencies? If the dependent project has added a new dependency, I won't be aware of it, right?

Comment: Yes, but question is saying: no direct change in project. Edit your question to be clear what you are asking